# Flex Box Divs Stacking instead of being horizontal

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I am trying to create a flexbox that has several divs inside of it. The divs have an image and a button that should stack but then I would like them to align in a row. I cannot seem to get them to actually go into a row instead they are stacking. Here is the HTML and CSS:

```css
.block2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.tan {
  background: #FFEFD5
}

.kite1 img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.kite1button img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 125px;
}

.kite2 img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.kite2button img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2 tan">
  <div class="kite1">
    <img src="kite1.png" />
    <div class="kite1button">
      <img src="deltasbutton.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="kite2">
    <img src="diamond-kite.png" />
    <div class="kite2button">
      <img src="diamondsbutton.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="kite3">
    <img src="specialty-kite.png" />
    <div class="kite3button">
      <img src="specialty-button.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `kite1`, `kite2`, and `kite3`, to `kite`.

Then style the `kite` class like so:

```
.kite {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

P.S. If you're going to be using an identifier (i.e. `class=` or `id=` or `data-whatever=`, etc) once, use `id`. If you plan on using an identifier on multiple elements, always use `class`. `id`s can only be used on one element, whereas `class` can be used on an indefinite number of elements.

```css
.block2 {
  display: flex;
}

.kite {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2 tan" >
  <div class="kite">
    <img src="kite1.png" />
    <div class="kite1button">
      <img src="deltasbutton.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="kite">
    <img src="diamond-kite.png"/>
    <div class="kite2button" >
      <img src="diamondsbutton.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="kite">
    <img src="specialty-kite.png"/>
    <div class="kite3button">
      <img src="specialty-button.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ajlec12 glad i could help. just remember: `class` is for when you want to style multiple elements. `id` is for when you want to style a single element. think of it like a school class full of children and each one of thosee children has a unique id card.